# passing array value to a controller and dispalying in a view In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Code Igniter. I am trying to pass an array from one controller to another to another controller and then displaying those value in a view. but its not working.

Controller No. 1

```
if($query)
{
    $data = array(
        'user' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'is_logged_in' => true
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('site/member_area',$data);
}
else {
    $this->index();
}
```

Controller No. 2 having member_area() function

```
function member_area()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
    $data['main_content'] = 'members_area'; 
    $this->load->view('includes/main_template',$data);
}
```

And in view i am trying to display display the 'user' name received in controller one using this statement in view

```
echo $user;
```

But its not displaying user name i.e $data['user']. the view is having only values received from controller No. 2

Comment: you need to make data a global variable

Comment: Vicky and Narendra Sisodia are correct. Once you have it set as session data, you can access that session data in any controller or function.

Answer (score 2):

You can define you session variables as

```
$this->session->set_userdata('mysession',$data);
```

and can access values from the session as

```
echo $this->session->userdata['mysession']['user'];// your email or username
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some changes within your code. As you were calling session value as simple array. This'll work for you..

**controller 1**

```
$data = array(
    'user' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'is_logged_in' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata('retrieveData',$data);
```

and within your view you can access that using

```
$retrieveData   = $this->session->userdata('retrieveData'); // will return the array

$userid = $this->session->userdata['retrieveData']['user'];// retrieving single element from session 
echo $userid;
```